# Is there a way to prevent N from being applied to all parts of an expression

Tags: evaluation

For example. If I have

```
N[x[1]]
```

how do I prevent it from returning

```
x[1.]
```

since I want to keep the variable as x[1]. I am using indexed variables like this in NonlinearModelFit where the form has N[expression involving indexed variables], but since the variable becomes x[1.] it no longer matches the parameter x[1] I use in NonlinearModelFit

Comment: Try `N[expr] /. x[i_] :> x[Round[i]]`

Comment: `SetAttributes[x, NHoldAll]`? There are also `NHoldFirst`, `NHoldRest`.

Comment: @Michael I think that is worthy of an answer.  If one doesn't already know about these attributes they are not necessarily easy to find.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can protect arguments inside brackets from `N` with the family of attributes, [`NHoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NHoldAll.html), [`NHoldFirst`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NHoldFirst.html), and [`NHoldRest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NHoldRest.html).

For an indexed variable such as `x[1]`, `x[2]`, etc., either

```
SetAttributes[x, NHoldAll]    (* what I would normally use *)
```

or

```
SetAttributes[x, NHoldFirst]  (* protects only the first argument *)
```

would keep the index from being numericized by `N`:

```
N[x[1]]
(*  x[1]  *)
```

Attributes of `x` can be cleared with [`ClearAttributes[x, <attribute>]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClearAttributes.html) or [`ClearAll[x]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClearAll.html), but ***NOT*** with [`Clear[x]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clear.html).

Built-in functions that require some or all arguments to be an integer (e.g. `Take`, `Part`), an exact number (e.g., `AlgebraicNumber`), or simply protected from being changed by `N` (e.g. `Subscript`) have one of these attributes.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a replacement rule matching the items you would like to convert.  Prior terms items in the replacement list can "protect" terms you would like to leave untouched.  E.g.

```
π x[1] + Sqrt[2^x[3]] + s[5] /. {u : _x | _s -> u, v_?NumericQ :> N[v]}
(* (2.^x[3])^0.5 + s[5] + 3.14159 x[1] *)
```