# N on equation with numbered variables

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, pattern-matching, polynomials

Say I have a system of polynomial equations in the variables `x[1],...,x[n]`. Sometimes want to make such equations numerical (as in: the coefficients become floats) by applying `N`. What happens, though, is that the indices of my variables also get converted to floats, e.g.:

```
(*Input*)
N[ x[1]^2 == x[2] ]

(*Output*)
x[1.]^2 == x[2.]
```

**Question:** Is there an elegant method to make polynomial equations numerical without affecting indexed variables. Note that in the above example the square does not get converted to a float and I would like to keep it that way.

Comment: see Michael E2 comment here [is-there-a-way-to-prevent-n-from-being-applied-to-all-parts-of-an-expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124927/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-n-from-being-applied-to-all-parts-of-an-expression/124937)
 which is to use `SetAttributes[x, NHoldAll]` and now `N[x[1]]` returns `x[1]` btw, these are called indexed variables in Mathematica.

Comment: You could first replace every integer by a machine number and then convert back the indices. E.g.: ` 2 x[1]^2 == 3 x[2] /. n_Integer :> N[n] /. x[n_] -> x[Round[n]]`